# Manually send soap request with complex type Array of String

Tags: soap, complextype

I want to use the "FindPOI" in ViaMichelin API

Here is the link of the SOAP WSDL : **https://webservices.viamichelin.com/ws2/services/FindPOI?wsdl**

I'm using a soap client called "SOAP UI" to send request manually but I have trouble formatting the complex type "ArrayOf_xsd_string" required in the WSDL.

```
<import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
 <complexType name="ArrayOf_xsd_string">
 <complexContent>
  <restriction base="soapenc:Array">
    <attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="xsd:string[]"/>
  </restriction>
 </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

Following is my guess but that doesn't work:

```
<datasheetContent xsi:type="ser:ArrayOf_xsd_string" arrayType="xsd:string[4]">
            <item xsi:type="xsd:string">tel</item>
            <item xsi:type="xsd:string">fax</item>
            <item xsi:type="xsd:string">email</item>
            <item xsi:type="xsd:string">iconId</item>
</datasheetContent>
```

using : *xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"*
and : *xmlns:ser="http://service.localization.ws2.viamichelin.com"*

Server response is :

```
<faultcode>soapenv:Server.userException</faultcode>
<faultstring>org.xml.sax.SAXException: No deserializer for {http://service.localization.ws2.viamichelin.com}ArrayOf_xsd_string</faultstring>
```

Any clue to successfully use this API method?